# Unable to resolve module `../images/icon.png` from `src\pages\home\index.js`:

Tags: android, react-native, paste, file-not-found

I'm going through a problem that apparently seems to be simple, but I'm not managing to solve it.

I'm starting an application using React Native, and I'm wanting to import an image that is in a folder, but it informs me that the image does not exist in the folder, the biggest problem is that this folder is two folders behind my index that I am calling, I already tried to return the folders with '../', '.' , but I am not able to solve it.

I need help, because I don't know what to do anymore.

I put below the image of the error that is happening to me

[react-native error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuYA2.png)

Comment: if you want to go two folders back use ```../../images/icon.png```

Comment: thanks a lot man, it worked here

Comment: I'm glad to help